# read string from file and turn into bitset<12>

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, bitset

Hi I'm trying to read string from txt file and transform it into binary file which is bitset<12> string form.

```
int main()
{
using namespace std;

std::ifstream f("fruit.txt");
std::ofstream out("result.txt");

std::hash<std::string>hash_fn;

int words_in_file = 0;
std::string str;
while (f >> str){
    ++words_in_file;
    std::bitset<12>* bin_str = new std::bitset<12>[3000];
    int temp_hash[sizeof(f)];
    std::size_t str_hash = hash_fn(str);
    temp_hash[words_in_file] = (unsigned int)str_hash;
    bin_str[words_in_file] = std::bitset<12>((unsigned int)temp_hash[words_in_file]);
    out << bin_str[words_in_file] << endl;
    delete[] bin_str;
}
out.close();
}
```

but there is error. How can I change it?

Comment: what kind of error? You should be more clear and provide some additional details

Comment: no operator "=" matches these operands operand types are: std::string = std::bitset<12U> this error

Comment: [why `while (!f.eof())` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: You can't assign to `str.c_str()`.

Comment: I changed it but still has same error

Comment: What are you trying to do in the line `str.c_str() = string`? You've never assigned anything to `string`, so why are you trying to assign that to `str.c_str()`?

Comment: I just want to get a data from file and convert into binary and save into bitset<12> string

Comment: So you need to loop through the contents of `str` and assign to the elements of `string`.

Comment: Yes!!That's what I want

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean by converting to binary. Why are you using `bitset<12>`? Bytes are 8 bits, while Unicode characters can be multiple bytes. Why 12 bits in your bitset?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142363/convert-char-or-string-to-bitset-in-c

Comment: Because my data must be '000000000000' in this form

Comment: That's why you should give meaningful names to your variables. Why do you have `str` and `string`? Call the bitset `bits` or something and then it becomes more clear - you're assigning the wrong way around and if you're trying to read a bitset then you'll need to use something like `bits = bitset<12>(str);`

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code that I wrote that turns the input file `"file.txt"` into binary. It does this by taking the ascii value of each character and representing that number as a binary value, although I'm not sure how to write `bin_str` to a file here.

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <streambuf>
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::ifstream f("file.txt");
    std::string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(f)),
                    std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());  // Load the file into the string
    std::bitset<12> bin_str[str.size()]; // Create an array of std::bitset that is the size of the string

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
        bin_str[i] = std::bitset<12>((int) str[i]); // load the array
        std::cout << bin_str[i] << std::endl; // print for checking
    }
}
```

#### SIDE NOTE:

`std::bitset<12>` may not be what you want, if you look at ascii characters the highest number you can have is 127 and in binary that's only 7 digits so I'd assume you'd want something more like `std::bitset<7>` or `std::bitset<8>`

EDIT:

If you want to write it to a file you'll need to open a file with `std::ios::binary` and then loop through the array of bitsets and write their unsigned long representative, given from `to_ulong()`, as a const char pointer (`(const char*)&ulong_bin`). Now when you open the file with a binary editor you will see the difference between the binary write and the regular write, but you'll notice that programs like `cat` can still decipher the binary you've written as simple ascii letters.

```
std::ofstream out("file.bin", std::ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) {
    unsigned long ulong_bin = bin_str[i].to_ulong();
    out.write((const char*)&ulong_bin, sizeof(ulong_bin));
}
```

**EDIT**: Credit to @PeterT

It has come to my attention that VLAs, variable length arrays, are not supported in C++11 and up so the line `std::bitset<12> bin_str[str.size()];` should be changed to one of the following:

```
std::bitset<12> *bin_str = new std::bitset<12>[str.size()]; // make sure you delete it later
// OR
std::vector<std::bitset<12>> bin_str(str.size());
// OR
std::unique_ptr<std::bitset<12>[]> str_ptr (new std::bitset<12>[str.size()]);
```

Comment: Thanks! but  this line has some error std::bitset<12> bin_str[str.size()]; IntelliSense: function call must have a constant value in a constant expression How can fix this error?

Comment: I also has this error when I run the code Unhandled exception at 0x0021BDBE in binaryFile.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000B0.

Comment: IntelliSense is probably just throwing a fit because std::bitset is a template so it thinks you're not making  an array but rather trying to use the birder like `std::birder<variables_cant_be_in_templates>` but the code works regardless and if you're getting an access violation that means that somewhere in the code something is trying to access restricted memory which means a pointer somewhere wasn't initialized or something like that. Do you mind compiling with '-g' and debugging the whole thing until you find the exact line that causes the problem

Comment: Thanks again! I changed the code in my question but I can't get the proper result I think I'm doing wrong in for loop but I don't know what is wrong. I'd like to get the result for full word For example, fruit.txt has {apple, orange} so I want to get the binary for apple so it'll be bin_s[0] , bin_s[1] but the result of bin_s[0] and bin_s[1] is same..

Comment: `std::bitset<12> bin_str[str.size()];` is using variable length arrays which is a C-language feature that's not supported by all C++ compilers. Something that you can do with standard C++ is `std::vector<std::bitset<12>> bin_str(str.size());`

Comment: My bad, you're right, you could however make it a pointer and use new couldn't you.

Comment: yes `std::bitset<12>* bin_str = new std::bitset<12>[str.size()];` would be possible, but since you'd have to manually delete that, I would prefer just the vector. But if you're hell-bend on the array but still want RAII you could also do `std::unique_ptr<bitset<12>[]> str_ptr (new bitset<12>[str.size()]);`

Comment: I delete[] bin_str  but it has triggered a breakpoint. I put std::bitset<12>* bin_str= new std::bitset<12>[str.size()+1]; and bin_str[str.size()] = '\0';

Comment: I don't think you need to null terminate it

Comment: So, do you mean I do not use bin_set[str.size()]='\0'?

Comment: Yeah since it's not a c-string or anything like that you don't necessarily need to null terminate it

Comment: I've get a error Unhandled exception at 0x000EDB35 in myprogram.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xB1514C80. It was because of the memory allocation, but I have no idea.

Comment: Perhaps you could show me all of the code you have written so I can more understand how you're getting this error, preferably as an edit to the question

Comment: I changed it on my question

Comment: You're not accessing the bitset array correctly and you're not accessing temp_hash correctly either, they're arrays so everything in the square brackets is an index so if you put in 0 then you get the first element in it. Also I don't think you really want to make an array of 3000 bitsets, I suggest you rewrite all of that code, remember bitset takes a integer (or character) as input and turns that into binary, so if you want to turn a number into binary you only need one bitset

Comment: @jack Also I think you probably don't want to hash your strings, when you hash something you can't reverse that. If you're trying to write the string out to a file in a binary format follow my answer, if you're trying to do something else please explain